# MVC gridview return popup with html when select filter or click next page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

mvc gridview return popup with html when select filter or click next page how can I fix this problem in this code show my partial gridview my view and controller action

PartialView

```
@{
    Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "TestList";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Admin", Action = "TestList" };

        settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
        settings.KeyFieldName = "ID";
        settings.CommandColumn.Visible = false;
        settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.Caption = "Edit";
            column.Visible = true;
            column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(content =>
                 ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                      Html.ActionLink("Edit", "TestListEdit", "admin",
                     new { id = content.KeyValue }, null)));
        });
        settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.Caption = "Delete";
            column.Visible = true;
            column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(content =>
                 ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                      Html.ActionLink("Delete", "TestListDelete", "admin",
                     new { id = content.KeyValue }, null)));
        });
        settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.Caption = "Manage";
            column.Visible = true;
            column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(content =>
                 ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                      Html.ActionLink("Manage Questions", "ManageQuestions", "admin",
                     new { id = content.KeyValue }, null)));
        });
        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = true;
        settings.Columns.Add("ID");
        settings.Columns.Add("Title");
        settings.Columns.Add("Description");
        settings.Columns.Add("Lang_ID");
        settings.Columns.Add("TryDescription");
    }).Bind(Model).Render();
}
```

this is my View

```
@model List<FastCreditTraining.Models.AdminTestListEditingModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestList";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_adminLayout.cshtml";
}
@{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = "English",
             Value = "1"
         });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = "Հայերեն",
             Value = "2",
         });
}
<body>

    <div style="display:inline-block;float:right; margin-right:30px; margin-top:10px">

        @Html.ActionLink("Create", "TestListCreate", "admin", new { @class = "LangButton" })

    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block">
        <form style="display:inline-block" name="tActive" id="tActive" method="get">

            <div style="margin-left:50px; display:inline-block;">
                <p style="display:inline-block">@Resources.Resource.DisplayActiveTests</p>
                @Html.CheckBox("tActive", true)
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left:100px; display:inline-block;">
                <p style="display:inline-block">@Resources.Resource.SetLanguageInterfaceEdit</p>
                @Html.DropDownList("langSwitch", listItems)
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name=" asdasd" value="Filter">
        </form>
    </div></body>
@{Html.RenderPartial("_GridViewTestListPartial",Model);}
```

And this is my controller action

```
![\[Authorize\]
        public ActionResult TestList(string tActive, string langSwitch)
        {

            //tActive and langSwitch choose getting tests with procedure getTests_Result
            List model1;
            if (tActive == null || langSwitch == null)
            {
                model1 = db.getTests(true, 1).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                model1 = db.getTests(Convert.ToBoolean(tActive), Convert.ToInt32(langSwitch)).ToList();
            }
            ///////////////////end of getting///////////////////

            // Fill new created model from database test lists and departaments and positions
            List _Departments = db.T_Department_Lang.ToList();
            List _Positions = db.T_Position_Lang.ToList();
            List _checkForDep = new List();
            List _checkForPos = new List();
            foreach (var item in _Departments)
            {
                _checkForDep.Add(new bool());
            }
            foreach (var item in _Positions)
            {
                _checkForPos.Add(new bool());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < model1.Count; i++)
            {
                allModels.Add(new AdminTestListEditingModel()
                {
                    ID = model1\[i\].ID,
                    Date_Added = model1\[i\].Date_Added,
                    Limit = model1\[i\].Limit,
                    IS_Active = model1\[i\].IS_Active,
                    Allow_Back = model1\[i\].Allow_Back,
                    Title = model1\[i\].Title,
                    Description = model1\[i\].Description,
                    Lang_ID = model1\[i\].Lang_ID,
                    S_Changed = model1\[i\].S_Changed,
                    Question_qnt = model1\[i\].Question_qnt,
                    Pos_Save = model1\[i\].Pos_Save,
                    Question_test_qnt = model1\[i\].Question_test_qnt,
                    TryDescription = model1\[i\].TryDescription,
                    qCount = model1\[i\].qCount,
                    TestList_Id = model1\[i\].ID,
                    Departments = _Departments,
                    Positions = _Positions,
                    checkForDep = _checkForDep,
                    checkForPos = _checkForPos
                });
            }
            //////////////// end fill //////////////////
            Session\["allModels"\] = allModels;
            return View(allModels);
        }][1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return **PartialView** instead of **View** to resolve this issue:

```
//return View(allModels);
return PartialView(allModels);
```

See the [Why can the alert message with the HTML/JavaScript/CSS content appear when using callback-aware extensions?](https://www.devexpress.com/kbid=KA20010) knowledge resource to learn more.